# CVS export inside a module

Tags: eclipse, version-control, module, export, cvs

I have a checked out a module. It's in `/home/user/repositories/repository`.

I want to export a folder inside this module. Suppose it's `folder3`.

```
/home/user/repositories/repository/folder1/folder2/folder3/
```

I get into

```
/home/user/repositories/repository/folder1/folder2/
```

and try to run

```
cvs export -r MYTAG -d MY_DIR folder3
```

But it doesn't work. I get:

```
-f server: cannot find module `folder3' - ignored
cvs [export aborted]: cannot expand modules
```

It's possible to export a folder inside a module inside Eclipse, or other visual editors. Which command they call do to it? Is it possible to "log" the executed command in visual editors?

Do I have to write the full path to export it, or does exist an alternative? What am I doing wrong? This can't be so difficult, I just want to export an specific folder from a cvs module using command line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad. I can export a tag that tagged a folder inside my module, using

```
cvs -d :pserver:user@localhost:2401/opt/cvs/ -q export -rProducts-250 -d Products-250 repository/folder1/folder2/folder3/
```